# Function template overloading with variadic templates: Intel c++ compiler version 18 produces different result from other compilers. Is intel wrong?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template<typename T, template<typename, typename ...> class A, typename ... Ts>
int a(A<T, Ts...> arg){
  return 1; // Overload #1
}

template<typename A>
int a(A arg) {
  return 2;  // Overload #2
}

template<typename T>
struct S{};

int main() {
  return a(S<int>());
}
```

Upon calling function `a` with an instance of a template class, I expect the compiler to select the more special function overload #1. According to the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxABZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5BwAMAQQKYAtgAdmSjgGYAwkrUbM2vQE9VmFk2WZSAagJmLVzLYB077dlvJmgwbfk7B3NLa1sAFSDHUJd3VwjBTzl5PBYCWyYIeWNIhLjPDOJgAEoOAHY%2BBVtq22JMAjEWWwBGbUrssoARZOT9dSZNXWCnMOytbGTU9Mz5QpLy9pra%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%2Bw%2BaVh1HcdMKEKcJDoOcESRdDJOXNdN23KjkBaMpXFkLyT3wIh7yJehbBvI07wfLgn30t9Iw/Ugvx/E1jOpLhmlcWhZFXZotG5RlwOZVlGS0RChQc9ELPlRVcPwiANSI0KSP1ci7xANymWaeiGCdJiPS9di5K4kMwwjSTo0E%2BsRrwRMxLTKVs1zfN60bYtS0k5Sqx9NTFtJYgW0LHS2D0l8e0M%2BBB1MscJ0s/EZ1sqQF1K6VpBXDct1sNyWkZLzXGaXyzwCy8gpCiiHy0SKjp4aKVQAy9XBZZogNAuCwPZRl%2BUFJEUPFRdHPK7ClShxCuHsqUZUhilSFTZ0zLoIA%3D), clang, gcc and intel up to version 17 actually do select overload #1. In contrast, later intel compiler versions (18 and 19) select overload #2.

Is the code ill-defined or are the more recent intel compiler versions wrong?

Comment: With `-O3` it becomes [a bit more readable](https://godbolt.org/z/ZR0vyV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [fails to call `a()`](https://godbolt.org/z/Eqr7oo) on icc 19.01:

```
template<template<typename, typename ...> class A, typename T, typename ... Ts>
int a(A<T, Ts...> arg){
    return 1;
}

template<typename T>
struct S{};

int foo()
{
    return a(S<int>());
}
```

It simply can't consider that `a()` as a candidate, and that's why the overloading is different in the question.

[C++17 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) says:

(where P is the template-template parameter, and A is the instantiating argument)

> **17.3.3** Template template arguments
>
> 3. A template-argument matches a template template-parameter P when P is at least as specialized as the
>      template-argument A. **If P contains a parameter pack, then A also matches P if each of A’s template parameters
>      matches the corresponding template parameter in the template-head of P.**

So far so good, `<int` argument head matches the parameter head `<T`.

> Two template parameters match
>   if they are of the same kind (type, non-type, template), for non-type template-parameters, their types are
>   equivalent (17.6.6.1), **and for template template-parameters, each of their corresponding template-parameters
>   matches, recursively.**

Still looks good, `int` and `T` match.

> When P’s template-head contains a template parameter pack (17.6.3), the template
>   parameter pack will match **zero or more** template parameters or template parameter packs in the template-head
>   of A with the same type and form as the template parameter pack in P (ignoring whether those template
>   parameters are template parameter packs).

This is more difficult to parse, but yet it seems OK to me. From what I understand, the compiler should have matched the argument with the template-template parameter. It explicitly talks about zero or more, and we have zero here.

Comment: Thus, it looks like there is a bug in the recent intel compilers and the above code is valid. Do you agree, @MichaelVeksler ?

Comment: @user2296653 yes, it looks like a bug in the recent intel compilers.